# Xamarin.Forms how to get the entered data from the pop-up window?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a pop-up window where user need to enter some information:

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"

. . .
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Enter name" />
            <Entry FontSize="20"
                   Placeholder=" Some_Thing" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Enter price" />
            <Entry FontSize="20"
                   Placeholder="250" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Button BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"
                FontSize="30"
                Text="Save"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked="new_product"
                />
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

the pop-up window is called as follows

```
    private void ShowNewUserPopup(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new NewUserPopupPage());
    }
```

but I have a question.how do I get the entered data from the pop-up window? before that, I tried the DisplayPromptAsync option and everything worked out.But what should I assign to the "result" variable this time? But since this is my first time working with pop-ups, I am not at all good at this, so I will be very grateful for your help:

```
async void new_product(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("New product", "name", "add", "cancel");
    if (result != null)
    {
        if (result.Length != 0)
        {
            await App.Database_Product.Create(new Database.Product(result, 100));
            name_colec.ItemsSource = await App.Database_Product.GetAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await App.Database_Product.Create(new Database.Product());
            name_colec.ItemsSource = await App.Database_Product.GetAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `PushAsync` does not return a value.  The easiest way to do this would be to subscribe to the page's OnDisappearing event

Comment: @Jason it would be great if I understood your idea..but I don't understand how to do it yet. Can you please tell me in more detail?

Comment: @Jason I tried, but I couldn't call this event :(  if it's not difficult for you, please explain how to do it

Comment: An example using [MessagingCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817294/8395242). Jason's suggestion of the OnDisappearing event would also work. Something like `var page = new MyPage();`, then `page.Disappearing += MyAwesomeEvent;`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass value through the Page Constructor. For example, when you want to pass the value which you enter in popup page and show it in another page when you do the navigation, the Page Constructor is an easy way.

Set the Name of the Entry in your popup page:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label  Text="Enter name" />
        <Entry x:Name="popup_Name" FontSize="20"
               Placeholder="Some_Thing" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label  Text="Enter price" />
        <Entry  x:Name="popup_Price" FontSize="20"
               Placeholder="250" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Button BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"
            FontSize="30"
            Text="Save"
            TextColor="White"
            Clicked="new_product"
            />
</StackLayout>
```

Set the constructor for the page which you want to navigate:

```
 public Page2(string name, string price)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Name.Text = name;//Name if the Label name of Page2
         Price.Text = price;
    }
```

Pass the value when you leave the popup page to another page. I use ContentPage for example:

```
  private async void new_product(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(popup_Name.Text, popup_Price.Text));
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
    }
```

**Update:**

```
     private async void new_product(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
         if (popup_Name.Text!= null)
      {
   
        await App.Database_Product.Create(new Database.Product(popup_Name.Text, 100));
        name_colec.ItemsSource = await App.Database_Product.GetAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        await App.Database_Product.Create(new Database.Product());
        name_colec.ItemsSource = await App.Database_Product.GetAsync();
    }

    }
```

Comment: I don't need to display on another page, I need to create a database item(based on the data entered in the pop-up window) to display it on the current page.

Comment: If you do not want to pass the value to another page, you could add it to the database directly. Please check my update.

Comment: there was another problem..name_colec is "x:Name= ", which is defined in the xaml file for the main page. so the popup file does not see name_colec. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You could not use the `x:Name` from one page to another page. It still seems the interaction between pages. You could reload the page with new `ItemsSource` when navigates. Or pass the value to another page and add it to the database and update the  `ItemsSource`.

Comment: I had no problems with name_collec before, because I used DisplayPromptAsync, and not a separate popup window (that is, it is like a new page). can you explain in more detail how to do this, please?

Comment: how do I transfer it to another page?won't there be the same problem that the transmitted elements will no longer be visible on another page?

Comment: `DisplayPromptAsync ` could interact with the user via a pop-up. It could be called in any Page, passing a title and message as string arguments. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups#display-a-prompt

Comment: But, according to your description, one way is to pass the value as page constructor what the code i showed in my reply. Another way is to pass as BindingContent. Check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#passing-data-when-navigating

Comment: I have defined x :Name for labels as name and price, but the cs file does not see them.why is this happening?

Comment: If you define the `x :Name` in MainPage, you could use it in MainPage.cs file. But you could not use it in another page like page1, page2.

Comment: I decided to do it a little differently, but your advice about the page constructor  was very useful to me. Thanks a lot!