# Xamarin.Forms/FreshMVVM - Yes/no style popup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

This is probably a quite silly question, but it nonetheless needs an answer:
I have created a small, custom MessageBox for my Xamarin.Forms project using Rg.Plugins.Popup - however, when trying to extend it to include a confirmation modal, I cannot find a way to detect whether the user has confirmed or cancelled the action from the popup.

Here's the code to open the popup

```
Message msgBox = new Message(); /*new instance of my Message wrapper class*/
msgBox.State = "msg_info";
msgBox.MessageTitle = "My_Message_Title";
msgBox.MessageText = "My_Message_Caption";

await CoreMethods.PushPopupPageModel<MessageBoxPageModel>(msgBox); /*using the FreshMVVM.Popup extension to navigate to the popup*/

/*need to check for confirmation here and delete the line or do nothing*/
```

So what I'm looking for, in short, is the appropriate way to detect whether the user has tapped the "Yes" or "No" button on the popup so I can, for example, delete a row from my database or not.

I looked into MessagingCenter but that seems to work from ViewModel to View, not ViewModel to ViewModel - Rg.Plugins.Popup suggest using a CallbackEvent, but CallbackEvents are, or so I've understood, not compatible with FreshMVVM/the MVVM pattern.

Comment: `MessagingCenter` is completely agnostic about the type of classes it is used with

Comment: Likewise, events don't care whether you are using MVVM or not. Have ViewModel declare the event `public event EventHandler MyEvent;`, then View can do `((MyViewModel)BindingContext).MyEvent += ...` to attach a callback.

Comment: I will look into both options and see which one works better. I have been doing WinForms applications for a good few years, but Xamarin.Forms seems to be a little different to what I'm used to - lot to learn!

Comment: [Pass back value from rgpopup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70817095/199364) might be useful. Shows use of MessagingCenter. That example isn't mvvm; you'll have to decide where to put `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` line of code.

Comment: Well if by "decide" you mean "try everything I can think of until it gets me angry enough to throw my laptop off the window" then... yes that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: So I'm almost there... MessagingCenter worked, but now when I tap "no" it doesn't do the delete action, but when I tap "delete" again after then "Yes" it throws an exception ("Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation")

Answer (score 0):

Just so this isn't kept open:

I ended up using a DevExpress Popup control as a Yes/No dialog - slightly less customization, but much more straightforward to use since I already had the DevExpress controls loaded.

Detail link for the DevExpress Popup control for those interested
https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.Popup.DXPopup